# "a becoming humility"? "Love is beautiful thing"?

Tags: articles

### "a becoming humility"(article before uncountable noun) is OK.

[My answer to another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/503091/352751) referring to [A | meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a):

> used before some uncountable nouns when you want to limit their
>   meaning in some way, such as when describing them more completely or
>   referring to one example of them:
>
> I only have a limited knowledge of Spanish.
>
> He has a great love of music.
>
> There was a fierceness in her voice.

But in [esl article usage rules](https://www.untdallas.edu/sites/default/files/page_level2/jmd0413/pdf/esl_article_usage_rules.pdf), an article before "thing"(a countable noun) can be omitted:

> Rule 37: Use Ø when generalizing about abstract nouns.
>
> ex: Love is beautiful thing.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ø is correct to use before "love". It's not correct to use before "thing". They say "Use Ø when generalizing about abstract nouns", so their focus is on showing you the correct usage regarding love, and weren't paying attention to whether their usage was correct for "thing".